# Windows archive symbolic links

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, 7-zip, hardlink

Is Windows able to store Symbolic links or Hard links in archive files?

I see 7-Zip has these options:

```
-snh : store hard links as links
-snl : store symbolic links as links
```

but trying them with Zip, Tar and 7z archive seems to store the actual file,
or some corrupted small file rather than something that can be a usuable link
upon extracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to only be an issue with p7zip on Windows:

https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin/2020-March/244075.html

The official version works as expected:

https://7-zip.org/download.html

Comment: Fellow googlers: unfortunately, the latest 7zip version (as of this writing) only stores/restores _file-type_ symlinks, but nonchalantly ignores _directory-type_ symlinks, at least on this Win7 box I'm at now. (Why this weird and cumbersome differentiation at all on Windows is another question worth asking...)

Answer (score 0):

If you choose .wim format, directory symlinks are stored but I have seen issues when extracting. For example, I have tried to archive (real) directories with three "types" of directory symlinks:

1. Link to a target within the archived directory.
2. Link to a target on the same drive as the archived directory, but not within it.
3. Link to a target on a different drive.

These are just arbitrary groupings of course. Anyway:

Type 1 is stored with a relative path and extracts fine as far as I have seen.

Type 2 is also stored with a relative path and works fine if you extract to the same location. Otherwise 7-zip will probably throw an error because of the relative path. Suppose you archive **D:\foo**, and **D:\foo\bar** is a symlink to **D:\bar**. The symlink target will be stored as **..\bar**. So if you extract to **E:\test** for example, 7-zip will try to create a symlink to **E:\test\bar**. If that doesn't exist it will throw an error and create an empty directory.

Type 3 is just weird. For example, I archived a directory on **D:** with a symlink to **E:\TEMP\zLogs**. When extracted to **F:\test**, the symlink pointed to **F:\test\TEMP\zLogs**.

I brought all this up on the [7-zip forums](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/1246effa09/). Dev responded but it wasn't too helpful.

Also, AFAICT direct extraction through File Explorer (etc) doesn't work right due to the privileges necessary to create symlinks. So it's necessary to run 7zFM as Administrator and extract with it.